# How do I make a single adapter act as multiple Wi-Fi access points?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router

My Wi-Fi router acts as FOUR different access points. These are respectively 2.4GHz, 5GHz, 2.4GHz guest, and 5GHz guest. I am wondering how this can be implemented on my laptop.

If my Wi-Fi adapter can connect to a 5GHz access point, does it mean I can also broadcast a 5GHz access point with it?

I did some ARP scans with my Wi-Fi router, all these four access points have the same MAC address on the gateway IP (192.168.1.1). However, all these access points have different BSSIDs, and none of these BSSIDs is the same with the MAC address. Are these access points actually running on the same adapter or not?

Answer (score 0):

> Are these access points actually running on the same adapter or not?

Yes they are. Most likely your router is based upon some stripped-down version of Linux, which can build *virtual interfaces* on a single physical interface, *i.e.* the physical NIC that does the actual broadcasting. Currently public documentation is scarce.

The MAC address you see is not that of the wifi NIC, because this is useless for wifi connections which do not use ethernet frames. The MAC address you see is, most likely, that of the ethernet NIC of your router, on the LAN side. The various LAN-side interfaces of a router are configured in a *bridge*, a sort of ideal, unified interface which puts together all of the collaborating interfaces, virtual or not. The bridge has a single IP address, so that your router, whether you are connected to it via wifi 2./5 GHz or via ethernet, always responds to the same address. When a bridge is created,it always takes on the MAC address of the first ethernet NIC, or a fake MAC,but never that of a wifi NIC.

> If my Wi-Fi adapter can connect to a 5GHz access point, does it mean I can also broadcast a 5GHz access point with it?

The answer to this question is that it depends on OS. On Linux, certainly. [This user](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2032357) figured out how to setup *hostapd* at 5GHz. On Windows, [there are many alternatives](http://alternativeto.net/software/hostapd/?platform=windows) to hostapd; since I do not use Windows, I do not know whether any of them works at 5GHz too, but it should be easy to try, most of them are free. You can also find [one program](http://alternativeto.net/software/hostapd/?platform=mac) for MAC.

Answer (score 0):

As of now*, you can use a single adapter to act as multiple APs on the same channel, but not simultaneously on different channels or bands.

A single adapter can only be on a single channel (and thus band) at a time, and the 802.11 protocols don't provide any good way for an AP to do TDD (Time-Division Duplexing) to switch back and forth between two channels. There's no way for **an AP to signal to its clients** that it'll be off channel for a moment an unable to receive their transmissions. So while the AP is off servicing the other channel (the other band), it'll miss transmissions from the clients in the first band, causing unacknowledged retransmissions, plummeting data rates, and other misfortune.

APs that support simultaneous dual-band (a.k.a. dual-band concurrent) operation always have two separate 802.11 adapters in them; one for 2.4GHz, and one for 5GHz. And the respective guest networks must be on the same channel as the main network in each band.

**now: There's been industry talk about creating Wi-Fi chipsets where a single adapter can do simultaneous dual-band, using some of its radio chains in one band/channel and another radio chain or two in another band, but I'm not aware of any of those products hitting the market yet here in mid-2015. That may change in the next year or two.*